# can we provide mobile site experience on desktop browser?

Tags: php, html, browser, curl, user-agent

Is it possible to show mobile site on desktop browser (with full functionality)?

If some website(for example yahoo or google) detects the user agent to decide where to redirect, I want to force it to show me the mobile version. Basically on the desktop browser, user needs to see how the mobile site would look. I tried user-agent with php-curl but it loads the first page only and that too without images.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible with add ons. For Firefox, there is [`User Agent Switcher`](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/user-agent-switcher/) that I'm currently using. For Safari, you can switch User-Agent directly in the Developer menu.

There is this [similar question](https://superuser.com/questions/98798/how-do-i-change-firefoxs-user-agent-via-aboutconfig) on SuperUser that describe how to change User-Agent via about:config in Firefox. Probably the only way that requires no installation of add-ons or extra softwares.

Comment: I would try to check the add-on you suggested. But is there any other way to do it without add-on? Because I can't tell the user to install the add-on and change the user-agent manually.

Comment: @DhairyaVora: Please see edit. There is apparently a way to do it. But the user will have to supply the User-Agent string themselves.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would redirect mobile traffic to a subdomain, such as `m.example.com`. Then, you can access `m.example.com` directly in a desktop browser and you will see what it looks like for mobile devices.

Comment: I want to show mobile version of the website which I don't own. I cannot change www.example.com to m.example.com. Site www.example.com is owned by someone else, I want to show how it would like on mobile device to my user. (I know it looks strange but its the question.)